Resume finetuning of LLM with LoRA
I have fine-tuned a Phi-3 for 1 epoch using LoRA as follows:
self.model=AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(self.model_args.model_name_or_path,**kwarg)
self.model = get_peft_model(self.model, self.lora_config)

Now I want to resume from existing LoRA weights by loading the weights as below:
self.model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(self.model , adapter)    
self.model.is_trainable = True    

This returns the following error:
  optimizer = DeepSpeedZeroOptimizer_Stage3(
  File "/PATH/miniconda3/envs/llms/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/zero/stage3.py", line 149, in __init__
        self.dtype = self.optimizer.param_groups[0]['params'][0].dtype
  

I can restart LoRA fine-tuning from the start but resuming fails with an optimizer error as above. Here is full error stack:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gpfs/u/scratch/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/research/FoodKG/models/Phi3/train.py", line 20, in <module>
    train()
  File "/gpfs/u/scratch/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/research/FoodKG/models/Phi3/train.py", line 14, in train
    custom_trainer.train()
  File "/gpfs/u/scratch/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/research/FoodKG/models/Phi3/core/model.py", line 273, in train
    trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=True)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1539, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1687, in _inner_training_loop
    model, self.optimizer = self.accelerator.prepare(self.model, self.optimizer)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py", line 1220, in prepare
    result = self._prepare_deepspeed(*args)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py", line 1605, in _prepare_deepspeed
    engine, optimizer, _, lr_scheduler = deepspeed.initialize(**kwargs)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/__init__.py", line 181, in initialize
    engine = DeepSpeedEngine(args=args,
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 307, in __init__
    self._configure_optimizer(optimizer, model_parameters)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 1258, in _configure_optimizer
    self.optimizer = self._configure_zero_optimizer(basic_optimizer)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 1582, in _configure_zero_optimizer
    optimizer = DeepSpeedZeroOptimizer_Stage3(
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/zero/stage3.py", line 149, in __init__
    self.dtype = self.optimizer.param_groups[0]['params'][0].dtype
IndexError: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gpfs/u/scratch/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/research/FoodKG/models/Phi3/train.py", line 20, in <module>
    train()
  File "/gpfs/u/scratch/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/research/FoodKG/models/Phi3/train.py", line 14, in train
    custom_trainer.train()
  File "/gpfs/u/scratch/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/research/FoodKG/models/Phi3/core/model.py", line 273, in train
    trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=True)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1539, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1687, in _inner_training_loop
    model, self.optimizer = self.accelerator.prepare(self.model, self.optimizer)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py", line 1220, in prepare
    result = self._prepare_deepspeed(*args)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/accelerator.py", line 1605, in _prepare_deepspeed
    engine, optimizer, _, lr_scheduler = deepspeed.initialize(**kwargs)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/__init__.py", line 181, in initialize
    engine = DeepSpeedEngine(args=args,
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 307, in __init__
    self._configure_optimizer(optimizer, model_parameters)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 1258, in _configure_optimizer
    self.optimizer = self._configure_zero_optimizer(basic_optimizer)
  File "/gpfs/u/home/TMPR/TMPRmhbt/scratch/miniconda3/envs/flax2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/runtime/engine.py", line 1582, in _configure_zero_optimizer 


Can you add the full error stack? I can only see that you got some error with the dtype. Maybe also try this solution as you are using LoRA (https://huggingface.co/docs/peft/v0.11.0/en/developer_guides/lora#load-adapters)

@SatyaPrakashDash full error stack added

The list index is out of range. As 0 is the first iterate, I think you have nothing saved in the optimizer dict. Maybe peft library doesn't save that for you.

if you are using deepspeed, you can try checking your (saved) model folder path if you have a file named *optim_states.pt. Ref: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/deepspeed?save=fp32#save-model-weights

I am using deep-seeps and *optim_states.pt is missing.

Then you don't have them. And anyway if you are using lora for saving, then they don't save optimizer states, they just save the model weights.

Hi @MohbatTharani, did you figure out the answer to the question? I am stuck in the this place as well. Appreciate your help.

I could not resume fine-tuning, so instead I continued from start until completed. Please share if you get the solution.

Someone solved this issue here: https://github.com/huggingface/peft/issues/184

base_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(base_model_id)
base_model.enable_input_require_grads() model =
PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, peft_adapter_path,
is_trainable=True) model._mark_only_adapters_as_trainable()

